# How to use wrap CPTAxisLabel into two lines using corePlot library in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-plot

I want to display CPTAxisLabel intwo lines if the text length is greater than 50 characters. How can i do that? I saw a method to draw a string in a rect. But I don't know how to call this method.
 If the following method is the solution for this please help me how to call this. Otherwise please provide me otherway.

Thanks in advance
-(void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withTextStyle:(CPTTextStyle *)style inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if ( style.color == nil ) return;

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGColorRef textColor = style.color.cgColor;

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, textColor);   
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, textColor);

CPTPushCGContext(context);  

UIFont *theFont = [UIFont fontWithName:style.fontName size:style.fontSize];

[self drawInRect:rect
        withFont:theFont
   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
       alignment:(UITextAlignment)style.textAlignment];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
CPTPopCGContext();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel—`CPTTextLayer` can do multi-line text. Insert newline characters ('\n') where you want line breaks. `CPTTextStyle` can control the text alignment (left, center, right).

Comment: I'm not getting multi-line text automatically.I'm having slice label of length 80 characters, but it is displaying only 50 characters remaining is cutting off. If I want to add '\n' means I have to calculate text length and I have to add \n when the length exceeds 50. Please provide me if there is another solution for this.